# Updating sprite's alpha as Scale increases

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, xna, monogame

I have a sprite which size changes from 0.6f to 2.0f during an animation.

At the same time I want its alpha value to change from 1.0f to 0 as its scale increase. So the sprite is fully opaque at 0.6f and gradually disappear until the size is 2.0f where it becomes totally transparent.

How do I correlate those values?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

```
spriteBatch.Draw(texture, Vector2.Zero, Color.White*alpha,null,0f,origin,scale,1f);
```

Where

```
  alpha = MathHelper.Clamp(0, 1 , 1 - (scale - startScale)/deltaScale);
```

In your case

```
 startScale = 0.6f,deltaScale = 2.0f-0.6f = 1.4f;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's going to be easier and more expandable if you animate each value separately. In this case scale and alpha, but the same logic could be applied to anything.

Animations are a function of time, so the variable you're missing here is how long you want the animation to last.

Each animation has a startValue and an endValue. From that you can derive 'change per second' like this:

```
var changePerSecond = (endValue - startValue) / totalSeconds;
```

Then in each frame, you simply increment the desired property by multiplying by the frame time (deltaTime), e.g.

```
scale += changePerSecond * deltaTime;
```

Okay, with the basic concept out of the way you can see how it would work for scale and alpha in your animation (using a 1 second animation as an example).

```
var scalePerSecond = (2.0f - 0.6f) / 1.0f;
var alphaPerSecond = (0.0f - 1.0f) / 1.0f;
```

Then in your update method..

```
scale += scalePerSecond * deltaTime;
alpha += alphaPerSecond * deltaTime;
```

Note that this is an example of the simplest linear animation off the top of my head to demonstrate the concept. You'll likely need other code to detect the end of the animation and what to do when it finishes.